# error "No file or directory found" loading model in Flask application

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras

I am using python 3.10 and visual studio code

I am trying to load a saved model in a flask python application, but I am getting the following error.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

from config import config

app=Flask(__name__)

import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model

img_height = 800
img_width = 600
model_dir = os.path.realpath('./modelo')
model_path = model_dir + '/modelo.h5'
pesos_path = model_dir + '/pesos.h5'

model = load_model(model_path)
model.load_weights(pesos_path)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

the ERROR:

2023-02-10 18:28:10.174416: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-02-10 18:28:10.269484: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:104] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2023-02-10 18:28:10.272356: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2023-02-10 18:28:10.272662: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2023-02-10 18:28:10.717915: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2023-02-10 18:28:10.717992: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2023-02-10 18:28:10.717998: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/desarrollo/cafeplag/src/app.py", line 19, in 
model = load_model(model_path)
File "/desarrollo/cafeplag/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/desarrollo/cafeplag/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/saving/legacy/save.py", line 227, in load_model
raise IOError(
OSError: No file or directory found at /desarrollo/cafeplag/modelo/modelo.h5

That could be happening? Please help. Thank you.

I have tried changing the model paths but nothing works.

Comment: We cannot validate if the path is correct or not, that is something you should know, so is the path in the error message correct or not?

Comment: `OSError: No file or directory found at /desarrollo/cafeplag/modelo/modelo.h5` Well, is that file path actually correct??

Comment: I have verified the path where the models are located and it is correct. I've even tried using relative paths but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not due to the path of the model.h5 file, but because the tensorflowRT library is missing in the correct versions.

Already solved.